# Using window.onscroll event to detect page/frame scrolling

Tags: javascript, events, dom, html, onscroll

I want to postion a `DIV` inside a page such that it is visible to the user even if the user vertically scrolls the page.

The page has a heading at the top of the page which is `75 px` tall. Now when the user is at the top of the page and has not scrolled vertically, the `DIV` must be postioned below the heading. However, once the user scrolls the page causing the heading to go out of sight, the same `DIV` must now be position at the top of the page (i.e. near the top edge of the browser viewport)

My big concern is the support for `window.onscroll` event on browsers. I checked QuirksMode for compatibility (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html). It seems to have decent compatibility on IE and Firefox. However the Safari and Chrome support seems a bit quirky. And both these browsers are part of my target browsers' list.

Can anybody tell me if the `window.onscroll` event is an effective way of detecting page/frame scrolls? Any other suggestions?

P.S. I have considered using the CSS `position: fixed` rule. It is close to the solution but the `DIV` is just stuck to one position and I cannot have it adaptively move based on the visiblity of the heading.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read about the clunkiness in WebKit on Quirksmode, you'll notice the following:

> Safari (but not on iPhone) and Chrome seem to monitor scrollTop acces in order to determine whether the user has scrolled an element. The log function of my test script changes scrollTop regularly, and Safari responds by firing a scroll event. Since the logging of this event changes the log element's scrollTop once more, scroll events will be fired continuously.
>   All this happens when the log element at the bottom of the page doesn't have a scrollbar yet, when it has a normal overflow: visible, and even when I set scrollTop to 0 each time a new event is logged. The buggy behaviour stops only when I remove the scrollTop line entirely.

This issue shouldn't affect what you're trying to achieve since you're not setting the `scrollTop` of any element.  You're attaching `onscroll` to the window, which appears to have no issues between any browser anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative method you could try. I use it to position a toolbar div on top of the page (works for ipad too).

Instead of using the onScroll event, I am using a timer to fire every 500ms  to detect where the windows is scrolled to via `scrollTop` . You could adjust the timer to about 200ms if you like.

Here's a stripped down sample of my code:

This jquery code checks when and if my dom element div named "floatlayer" (which is a div that contains my buttons toolbar) is ready and then calls the function `setRepeater`

```
$(#floatlayer").ready(function () {
    return setRepeater();
});
```

Then, this is the function that creates a timer to keep executing the function "keepIncrease" every 500ms

```
 function setRepeater() {
        aTimer = window.setInterval("keepIncrease()", 500);
        return false;
    }
```

This is the function keepIncrease() which is repeated every 500ms and is responsible to position the toolbar div based on the current window scrolled position :

```
function keepIncrease() {
    var divToolbar = $("#floatlayer")[0];

    var currentPos =  $(window).scrollTop();
    divToolbar.style.top = currentPos + "px";

    return false;
}
```

Something else out of topic: 
If your content is inside an iframe, you could also use $(window.parent).scrollTop() instead of $(window).scrollTop()

Answer (score 0):

<s>Why not just use "fixed"?</s>

Oh, I see, I missed the part about the header.

You could still utilize the position:fixed option, though. You would just set the position against "body" initially (accounting for the 75px gap), and once the header leaves viewability, you can realign the div against the top of the viewport. But without using onscroll in some way or another you probably won't be able to do what you want to do. Sometimes you just have to make the decision: Do I want the feature more, or the people more?